# Python data Manipulation: Splitting Data from one column to make more rows in the same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, data-manipulation

So my input is:

```
   Col1         Col2      Col3 Col4
0   123  abc,def,ghi  Country1  XXX
1   456      pqr,stu  Country2   XX
2   789          xyz  Country2   YY
```

I want my output as :

```
   Col1      Col2    Col3   Col4
0    abc     123  Country1    XXX
1    def     123  Country1    XXX
2    ghi     123  Country1    XXX
3    pqr     456  Country2     XX
4    stu     456  Country2     XX
5    xyz     789  Country2     YY
```

What would be the most pythonic way to do this pls? Thanks vm!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for creating `Series` for [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original `DataFrame`:

```
print (df.Col2
      .str
      .split(',',expand=True)
      .stack()
      .reset_index(drop=True, level=1)
      .rename('Col2'))

0    abc
0    def
0    ghi
1    pqr
1    stu
2    xyz
Name: Col2, dtype: object


print (df.drop('Col2', axis=1)
             .join
             (
             df.Col2
             .str
             .split(',',expand=True)
             .stack()
             .reset_index(drop=True, level=1)
             .rename('Col2')           
             ))

   Col1      Col3 Col4 Col2
0   123  Country1  XXX  abc
0   123  Country1  XXX  def
0   123  Country1  XXX  ghi
1   456  Country2   XX  pqr
1   456  Country2   XX  stu
2   789  Country2   YY  xyz
```

Comment: aha - `expand=True` in split + stack!! thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

using `extractall` and `join`

```
d1 = df.Col2.str.extractall('([^,]+)') \
       .rename(columns={0: 'Col2'}) \
       .reset_index(1, drop=True)

df.drop('Col2', 1).join(d1).reindex_axis(df.columns, 1)
```

[image]

Comment: ah interesting - didn't know about `extractall` .. thanks will try it out